# Вставка элемента в TreeView QT [QAbstractItem]

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, viewmodel, qt6

Пытаюсь реализовать свою модель дерева через QAbstractItem. У меня есть метод *SetEmployees*, который добавляет элементы с использованием *beginInsertRow()*. Но, что он есть(beginInsertRow), что нет, элементы все равно добавляются, но не отображаются, пока не потянуть за горизонтальные хэдеры. Хочу реализовать возможность добавления отдельной строки *InsertRow* (как отдела, так и рабочего), но не получается. Новый элемент не отображается в view. Скорее всего, неправильно описал модель. Буду очень благодарен за любую помощь!

Вот структура элемента

```
struct infoItem{
    QString departmentName;
    Person person;
    QVector<infoItem *> childrens;
    infoItem *parent;
    int avgSalary;
    int employeeCount;

};
```

Код модели:

```
DepartmentModel::DepartmentModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractItemModel{parent}
{
    rootItem = new infoItem();
    rootItem->parent = nullptr;
    rootItem->departmentName = tr("Департаменты разработки");

}

QModelIndex DepartmentModel::index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const
{

    if (!hasIndex(row, column, parent))
            return QModelIndex();

    infoItem *item;
    if(!parent.isValid())
        item = rootItem;
    else
        item = static_cast<infoItem* >(parent.internalPointer());

    infoItem *child;
    child = item->childrens.at(row);
    if(child)
        return createIndex(row, column, child);
    return QModelIndex();
}

QModelIndex DepartmentModel::parent(const QModelIndex &child) const
{
    if (!child.isValid())
        return QModelIndex();

    infoItem *childItem = static_cast<infoItem*>(child.internalPointer());
    infoItem *parentItem = childItem->parent;

    if (parentItem == rootItem)
        return QModelIndex();

    int row = parentItem->childrens.indexOf(childItem);
    return createIndex(row, 0, parentItem);
}

int DepartmentModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    infoItem *item;
    if(!parent.isValid())
        item = rootItem;
    else
        item = static_cast<infoItem*>(parent.internalPointer());

    return item->childrens.count();

}

int DepartmentModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    return 3;
}

QVariant DepartmentModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();


    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
        infoItem *item = static_cast<infoItem* >(index.internalPointer());
        if(index.column() == 0){
            if(item->childrens.count() == 0)
                return item->person.surname + " " + item->person.name + " " + item->person.middlename;
            return item->departmentName;
        }
        if(item->childrens.count() != 0){
            switch (index.column()) {
                case 1:
                    return item->employeeCount;
                break;
            case 2:
                return item->avgSalary;
                break;
            }
        }
    }





    return QVariant();
}

QVariant DepartmentModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole){
        switch(section){
        case 0:
            return rootItem->departmentName;
            break;
        case 1:
            return "Количество сотрудников";
            break;
        case 2:
            return "Средняя зарплата";
            break;
        }

    }

    return QVariant();

}

void DepartmentModel::SetEmployees(QList<Department> list)
{
    QModelIndex index = createIndex(rootItem->childrens.count(), 0, rootItem);
    beginInsertRows(index, rootItem->childrens.count(), rootItem->childrens.count() + list.count() - 1);

    foreach(auto department, list){
        infoItem *new_department = new infoItem();
        new_department->parent = rootItem;
        new_department->departmentName = department.name;
        rootItem->childrens.append(new_department);

        double avg = 0;

        foreach(auto person, department.employees){
            infoItem *child_person = new infoItem();
            child_person->parent = new_department;
            child_person->person = person;
            new_department->childrens.append(child_person);
            avg += child_person->person.salary;

        }
        new_department->employeeCount = new_department->childrens.count();
        new_department->avgSalary = avg / new_department->employeeCount;
    }
    


    //endInsertRows();
    

}

void DepartmentModel::InsertRow(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if(!index.isValid()){
        QModelIndex newIndex = createIndex(rootItem->childrens.count(), 0, rootItem);
        beginInsertRows(newIndex, 0, 1);

        infoItem *item = new infoItem();
        item->departmentName = "[Новый департамент]";
        item->employeeCount = 0;
        item->avgSalary = 0;
        item->parent = rootItem;
        rootItem->childrens.append(item);

        endInsertRows();

    }
    else{
        infoItem *parent = static_cast<infoItem *>(index.internalPointer());
        QModelIndex newIndex = createIndex(parent->childrens.count(), 0, parent);
        beginInsertRows(newIndex, parent->childrens.count(), parent->childrens.count());

        infoItem *item = new infoItem();

        item->parent = parent;
        item->person = Person();
        parent->childrens.append(item);
        endInsertRows();
    }

}

Qt::ItemFlags DepartmentModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = QAbstractItemModel::flags(index);
    if(index.isValid())
            flags |= Qt::ItemIsSelectable;
    infoItem *item = static_cast<infoItem *>(index.internalPointer());
    if(item->parent == rootItem)
        flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    return flags;
}

bool DepartmentModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    if(role == Qt::EditRole && index.isValid()){
        infoItem *item = static_cast<infoItem *>(index.internalPointer());
        if(item->parent == rootItem){
            item->departmentName = value.toString();
            emit dataChanged(index, index);
            return true;
        }
        infoItem *parent = item->parent;
        parent->avgSalary -= item->person.salary / parent->employeeCount;
        item->person = unpackPerson(value);
        parent->avgSalary += item->person.salary / parent->employeeCount;
        emit dataChanged(index.parent(), index);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Надо так и делать (немного упрощу код, но суть должна быть ясна).

```cpp
// Отдел
struct Department {
    QList<Person> employee;
    QString name;
}

// Список отделов
struct Departments {
    QList<Department> deps;
}

class DepModel: public QAbstractItemModel {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    Departments root; // Можно и просто QList<Department> root; но, вам виднее
}
```

Далее, вы хотите иметь возможность добавлять новые отделы:

```cpp
class DepModel: ... {
public:
    QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) {
        ...     
    }
    // Добавим новый отдел в конец списка
    void append(const Department& dep) {
        // По умолчанию, метод index() должен вернуть QModelIndex, 
        // соответствующий вашему root (parent = QModelIndex())
        QModelIndex idx = this->index(0, 0);

        // Получаем текущее количество отделов разработки
        int count = root.deps.count();
        beginInsertRow(idx, count, count);
        root.deps.append(dep);
        endInsertRow();
    }
}
```

Добавление сотрудника:

```cpp
class DepModel: ... {
public:
    // Добавление сотрудника в отдел, которому соответствует индекс depIdx
    void append(const Person& person, int depIdx) {

        // Корневой индекс
        QModelIndex rootIndex = this->index(0, 0);
        // Индекс отдела
        QModelIndex depIndex = this->index(depIdx, 0, rootIndex);

        Department& dep = root.deps[depIdx];
        beginInsertRow(depIndex, dep.empCount(), dep.empCount());
        dep.employee.append(person);
        endInsertRow();
    }
}
```

И так далее, и тому подобное.